# Echo date/month from database and echo current year

Tags: php, date, datetime, echo

I would like my output to be - **05/12/2016 <--- year depends on the current year.**

`$date='05/12/2014';
 $current_year='date("Y")';`

I've tried combine like below but clearly its wrong. Please help me, how do I combine these two to get my desire output?

```
$date =(date("d/m", strtotime($date'])) / date("Y"));
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the date above 05/12/2014 and simply change the year to 2016?

If so, I would put your date into a DateTime object then get out each part of the date using format and then set a new DateTime object using the new year...

Some people will say to use explode on the date... try to refrain from that because the format of a date can change e.g. m/d/y d/m/y etc

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can work. Just adapt it a bit:

```
date("d/m", strtotime($date)) . '/' . date("Y");
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by others, with this type of date format (d/m/Y) you might have issues when date is '25/12/2014'. To be sure your code works in any case use [date_parse_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) to control your date format:

```
$date = '25/12/2014';
$date_array = date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y',$date);

echo $date_array['day'] . '/' . $date_array['month'] . '/' . date("Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date='05/12/2014';

echo date("d/m", strtotime($date)) ."/". date("Y");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this. Concate your `/` and remove `]` .You need to format your database date.It should work.**Try:**

```
$databaseDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("31/12/2014")); //you need to format your databse Date
$mergeDate = date("d/m", strtotime($databaseTime)) . '/' . date("Y");
echo $mergeDate;
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/1mvf)**